# How to reduce the spring startup time

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

We are trying to deploy our spring boot application into AWS Lamda. While triggering an API through API gateway it is taking more time(28 to 30sec) to start up so I am getting timeout error as a response. And we configured Lamda memory as 512 MB.

Tried with the below changes as well:

1. Removed Unused dependencies from pom file.
2. Made static configuration for database connection.
3. Configured spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto as none for avoiding the database initialization.
4. With spring.main.lazy-initialization=true
5. By @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Adding logs:

```
.   ____          _            __ _ _
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
\\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
'  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
:: Spring Boot ::                        
2021-09-27 09:08:38.938  INFO 1 --- [           main] lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry             : Starting LambdaRTEntry using Java 1.8.0_302 on 169.254.30.181 with PID 1 (/var/runtime/lib/LambdaJavaRTEntry-1.0.jar started by sbx_user1051 in /)
2021-09-27 09:08:38.941  INFO 1 --- [           main] lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry             : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-09-27 09:08:43.719  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-09-27 09:08:44.748  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 983 ms. Found 20 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-09-27 09:08:47.871  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-09-27 09:08:48.085  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version [WORKING]
2021-09-27 09:08:48.906  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-09-27 09:08:49.322  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-09-27 09:08:50.697  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-09-27 09:08:50.779  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2021-09-27 09:08:57.684  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-09-27 09:08:57.759  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-09-27 09:09:07.124  INFO 1 --- [           main] lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry             : Started LambdaRTEntry in 30.106 seconds (JVM running for 31.393)
2021-09-27 09:09:07.188  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.f.c.c.BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry : Looking up function 'function' with acceptedOutputTypes: []
2021-09-27 09:09:07.190  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.f.c.c.BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry : !!! Failed to discover function 'function' in function catalog. Function available in catalog are: [lamdaFunction, functionRouter]
2021-09-27 09:09:07.190  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.f.c.c.BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry : Looking up function 'consumer' with acceptedOutputTypes: []
2021-09-27 09:09:07.190  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.f.c.c.BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry : !!! Failed to discover function 'consumer' in function catalog. Function available in catalog are: [lamdaFunction, functionRouter]
2021-09-27 09:09:07.191  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.f.c.c.BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry : Looking up function 'supplier' with acceptedOutputTypes: []
2021-09-27 09:09:07.191  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.f.c.c.BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry : !!! Failed to discover function 'supplier' in function catalog. Function available in catalog are: [lamdaFunction, functionRouter]
2021-09-27 09:09:07.192  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.f.c.c.BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry : Looking up function 'lamdaFunction' with acceptedOutputTypes: []
```

Comment: Please don't add logging as screenshots, those are unreadable. Add the logs as logs. Figure out what is taking so long and improve that, randomly excluding things isn't the best way to improve performance. Also I doubt excluding the datasource config will do anything as you are using a database judging from your logs.

Answer (score 1):

1. Based on my experience in general the warm up time is longer for Spring Boot services but if you have more requests coming in a short period, from the second call it should be faster.
2. If your client can wait a little bit more than 30 seconds, then you can increase the timeout for the Lambda function itself: Lambda/Function/General Configuration/Timeout.
3. Be careful with connecting to a DB from Lambda, because as Lambda scales out, you may run out of DB connections: https://solidstudio.io/blog/aws-handle-database-connection

Answer (score 1):

For first time startup, generally Spring Boot with Hibernate does not go well with quick startup environments like Lambdas. There are few techniques which can be tried as mentioned [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-aws-lambda-hibernate) or an alternate solution like [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/) is better fit. Many people have also gone the route of perpetually warming up the lambdas by pinging.

Your connection-pool (HikariCP) setup is quite fast so it does not look like database connection issue

```
2021-09-27 09:08:49.322 INFO 1 --- [ main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Starting... 
2021-09-27 09:08:50.697 INFO 1 --- [ main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
```

Most of your time seems to be spending on loading Spring classes and setup (approx 5s)

```
2021-09-27 09:08:38.941 INFO 1 --- [ main] lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default 
2021-09-27 09:08:43.719 INFO 1 --- [ main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT
```

And also Hibernate setup ( which scans the entities, creates auto-generated queries etc.) - approx 10s

```
2021-09-27 09:08:47.871 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default] 2021-09-27 09:08:48.085 INFO 1 --- [ main] org.hibernate.Version : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version [WORKING] 2021-09-27 09:08:48.906 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final} 
2021-09-27 09:08:49.322 INFO 1 --- [ main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Starting... 
2021-09-27 09:08:50.697 INFO 1 --- [ main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Start completed. 
2021-09-27 09:08:50.779 INFO 1 --- [ main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect 2021-09-27 09:08:57.684 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform] 
2021-09-27 09:08:57.759 INFO 1 --- [ main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

Hope you are not using schema auto-update feature of hibernate because then it spends some time there as well.